# Any examples of creating a windows service in C/C++ ? (No GUI)

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, windows-services

This is a great reference of how it all works at a relatively low level:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685967%28VS.85%29.aspx

However, is there a working C/C++ example that shows how to install and run code as a service - all done in code, not using any of the windows gui?